Why are there different API Responses from Postman and .NET MAUI app for the same Request?
I'm encountering an issue where the same API request returns different results when sent from Postman versus my .NET MAUI application. The API in question is a login endpoint that performs validation on the provided email and password fields.
API Controller Implementation:
Here’s the relevant section of the API controller handling the login request:
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion(ApiVersions.V1)]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/users")]

public class UsersController (ISender sender, IMapper mapper) : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LogInUserRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var command = new LogInUserCommand(request.Email, request.Password);
        Result<string> result = await sender.Send(command, cancellationToken);

        if (result.IsFailure)
        {
            return Unauthorized(result.Error);
        }

        var response = new AccessTokenResponse(result.Value);
        return Ok(response);
    }
}

API Details:

Endpoint: domain.com/api/v1/users/login
Method: POST
Content-Type: application/json
Request Body:

{
  "email": "",
  "password": ""
}

Postman Response:
When I send the request from Postman, I receive a detailed error response with multiple validation messages:
{
  "type": "ValidationFailure",
  "title": "Validation error",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "One or more validation errors has occurred",
  "errors": [
    {
      "propertyName": "Email",
      "errorMessage": "'Email' must not be empty."
    },
    {
      "propertyName": "Email",
      "errorMessage": "'Email' is not a valid email address."
    },
    {
      "propertyName": "Password",
      "errorMessage": "'Password' must not be empty."
    },
    {
      "propertyName": "Password",
      "errorMessage": "The length of 'Password' must be at least 6 characters. You entered 0 characters."
    }
  ]
}

.NET MAUI Response:
However, when sending the same request from my .NET MAUI application using HttpClient, the response is less detailed and only returns a single validation error message:
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "errors": {
    "Email": ["The Email field is required."]
  },
  "traceId": "00-bc587b4c97e7b25236f0e375e0b4bc4a-e7b5ce673a92e452-00"
}

.NET MAUI Implementation:
Here’s the code I’m using in my .NET MAUI application:
 public class AccountService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
    public async Task<Result<AccessTokenResponse>> LoginAsync(LogInUserRequest model)
    {
        using HttpClient client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("SpardaApiClient");
        try
        {
            var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(model), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync($"users/login", content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseData = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<AccessTokenResponse>();

                return Result.Success<AccessTokenResponse>(responseData);
            }

            var errorContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var result = HandleErrorResponse(errorContent, response.StatusCode);
            return result;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Result.Failure<AccessTokenResponse>(Error.Validation());
        }
    }
}

Question:
What could be causing the API to return different responses for the same request when sent from Postman versus a .NET MAUI app? Are there any known differences in how Postman and HttpClient handle requests or process responses that could explain this discrepancy?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

What HandleErrorResponse does? And also are you sure httpClientFactory.CreateClient("SpardaApiClient") creates the SAME call that postman does?

HandleErrorResponse is nothing just handle errorContent that gets error response. Yes I created the same and I also used HttpClient instead of IHttpClientFactory and I got the same result.

I'd guess that Postman is adding some header values that impact the response.  Have you verified that both requests are passing an identical request object into the API method?

Postman has a control panel where you can get the entire HTTP Request.  Postman is very robust and will add HTTP headers automatically.

You can refer to the similar case: Differences between using C# HttpClient API and the Postman testing? Client call works on Postman, but not C# httpClient getAsync.

With limited information, I can only make some assumptions, which I hope are correct based on my expertise.
The first response you shared (from Postman) appears to be a FluentValidation configured validation error, while the MAUI response looks like reflects the default ModelState error. When you cover your controller with the [ApiController] attribute, this error handling is automatically injected.
Whether the request is sent via Postman or MAUI, it does not generate entirely separate responses. However, the requests are indeed different. If you use a web tracker to observe the requests, you will notice differences.
Again, I’m just speculating, but it seems like your LogInUserRequest model class contains an Email property with the [Required] attribute. If you remove these DataAnnotations and allow FluentValidation to validate your model, you will likely get the first response.
